# Receive today files via adb pull

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I'm trying to create a `.bat` file that should copy today's photos to PC.

I already create a command that lists all today filenames to `t.txt` file:

```
adb shell find /sdcard/DCIM/Camera -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f > t.txt
```

And I already know that I can copy single photo via command like that:

```
adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200526_000742.jpg IMGS/IMG_20200526_000742.jpg
```

But how can I combine this two commands to pull photos?

Comment: Have you tried piping the output of the first command like so: `adb shell find /sdcard/DCIM/Camera -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f > t.txt | adb pull`?

Comment: This might work `powershell -command "adb pull $(adb shell find /sdcard/DCIM/Camera -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -type f)"`